# Couldn't find Post without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags

I am trying to get my posts tagged with a certain tag to render. My code in the view is

Views/posts/sports.html.erb

```
 <% my_posts = post.find_by_tag("sports") %>
 <%= my_posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %><br />
    <%= post.body %><br />
 <% end %>
```

my controller for this looks like

```
 def sports
     @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @title = "Newest"


     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json { render :json => @users }
     end
 end
```

I know I have to define the @post variable but I'm not sure what to define it as.

UPDATE

The problem I'm having is a "Couldn't find Post without an ID" error

Second UPDATE

```
   def find_by_tag name 
     Tag.find_by_name(name).posts 
   end
```

Comment: params[:id] must be blank (nil)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem, based on what is shown here, is that you are defining instance variables with Post object(s) in the controller, and then not using them for anything in the view. To retrieve a collection of all the posts tagged "sports," you'd do the following in the controller:

```
@sports_posts = Post.find_by_tag("sports")
```

and in the view:

```
<% @sports_posts.each do |post|
  etc...
```

To add pagination, you can just chain that method to the original:

```
@sports_posts = Post.find_by_tag("sports").paginate(:page => params[:page],
                                                    :per_page => 10)
```

This is different from your snippet, where you define a `@posts` variable that returns a collection of 10 `Post` objects, and `@post` which simply finds a post object based on the id passed by the submitting form params. My guess is that this controller action is not getting created by a form submission, so no params are passed, and therefore `params[:id]` is nil, hence the error messages you see. In any event, unless you need either of those items in your view (and there's nothing here to suggest they're being used for anything), there's no reason to create them.

What you do need is a collection of posts tagged "sports", which is what the call above accomplishes. It looks like you are trying to do that with `post.find_by_tag("sports")` in the view. The problem is that you are calling the `find_by_tag` method on `post`, which *doesn't exist*. `Post` exists - that's the Post class, and probably what you mean to be calling. Just changing `post` to `Post` would probably get you where you want, but content retrieval and presentation are better separated if you create your objects in the controller and then use the view to simply render their attribute data (per the example above).

Comment: First I would like to thank you very much for the great answer to my question. I greatly appreciate the level of detail and effort you put into helping me out with my problem. I tried your solution and the new error I receive is that find_by_tag is not defined. It currently is defined in my Post Model and the call is working in my show.html.erb and _post.html.erb views but for some reason is not working in this view with this controller. I will update my question to show how I've defined it in my Model.

Comment: Are you using acts_as_taggable_on or some other library? If so, those provide specific methods to get a collection of objects tagged with some value. For example acts_as_taggable_on provides a "tagged_with" method, so you'd just replace my first line above with `@sports_posts = Post.tagged_with("sports").paginate(...)`, as opposed to going to the trouble of coming up with your own method. Note also that your method is unnecessary - `Tag.find_by_name("something").posts` would return a collection of posts objects associated with Tags named "sports," which is just what you need.

Comment: well first I am not using acts_as_taggable,I'm working off code that I found in a railcasts in relation to virtual attributes. I wasn't able to find a suitable tutorial or explanation of how to implement acts_as_taggable so I decided to go with way and this is the final barrier in implementing.

Comment: That's tougher. I'm sorry you didn't find a tutorial that worked for you - I think the readme for the gem is pretty decent - https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on, but it does dive right into complicated cases so it's not easy to see how it works in the simplest case. I'd really recommend trying to get through it. The installation instructions here - http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2009/05/08/using-rails-acts-as-taggable-on-plugin/ are for Rails 2 (use the readme instructions for Rails 3), but the section on usage is a little bit more straightforward. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: I found a tutorial that worked and was able to implement acts-as_taggable-on so thank you for getting me to relook at that option. For anyone else that looks at this post that needs help the link is http://g-p.si/posts/tagging-with-acts-as-taggable-on

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what's going wrong, you only say what you're trying to do.

A few things to help debug whatever it is you are seeing:

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

In your main layout, this will dump the params hash and may lend a clue.

Also,

```
rake routes
```

Make sure you are looking for the right parameter key(s).

In the snippet you provided, you have an equals in front of the `my_posts.each ...` line, I am not an ERB expert, but I would think you would not want that, instead this:

```
<% my_posts = post.find_by_tag("sports") %>
<% my_posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %><br />
  <%= post.body %><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just updated with the problem, thanks for pointing that out.